# RegEx to test a value with honouristics (Mr, Miss, Mrs, Master) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
    ti= /\bMrs\b|\b Mr\b|\bMiss\b|\bMaster\b/;
    if(!ti.test(title.value)){
        alert("Error: Please check Title");
        return false;
    }
```

I am trying to compare the input of title with the following honourisitics, but even when i type in Miss for example, the alert still appears, what type of regExpression should i do here when i want to compare my input value with full words?

Comment: No repro. `!/\bMrs\b|\b Mr\b|\bMiss\b|\bMaster\b/.test('Miss')` gives me `false`.

Comment: Please debug, what `title.value` retuns..

Comment: @callback title.value brings back whatever is inputted into the form

Comment: @Aran-Fey i want to return true because they match

Comment: @RachelMcConnell, yes, but what Aran meant is that, doing `/\bMrs\b|\b Mr\b|\bMiss\b|\bMaster\b/.test('Miss')` does indeed return true. So the regex IS correct. (Except for an extra space that you have before Mr)..

Comment: Yes this is working as expected. I put a visual reference together...
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-da8ae5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet where I made the following modifications:

- simplified the regex to make it easier to read,
- created a function to use the `test` multiple times easily.

```js
values = ["Hmm", "Miss Parker", "Mr. Anderson", "Little Red"];
ti = /\b(Mrs|Mr|Miss|Master)\b/;

// Created function
function test(value) {
  if (!ti.test(value)) {
    console.log("Error: Please check Title");
  } else {
    console.log("Ok,", value);
  }
}

// Output
test(values[0]);
test(values[1]);
test(values[2]);
test(values[3]);
```

Feel free to comment if you are still having an issue or want to add some test cases!

Hope it helps.

Comment: @RachelMcConnell I'm glad it helped. :)